# PSU-powered, motherboard case-fan header-controlled, multiple fan controller

Tags: cooling, fan-controller

Is there a fan controller, that plugs into the case fan motherboard header, but actually takes power from the PSU, and therefore can power multiple fans but control speed based on sensors built-into the motherboard? I know I could connect them to the PSU but this PC isn't always being taxed heavily and I don't want the noise if I can avoid it.

Motherboard is ASRock X570 PRO4.

Comment: I've seen this type of controller with manual rheostat adjustment. Will look for one which interfaces to a motherboard. Which make and model of motherboard? Please click [edit] and put that in your question.

Comment: Unless you are using server-grade fans that draw a lot of power, or really a lot of fans, you could just as easily connect several fans to a single connector on the board with a splitter cable. Not many motherboard vendors specify it exactly, but fan headers on motherboards can usually handle 1A and more. With most desktop-grade fans drawing less than a quarter of that.

Comment: Thanks for replying. The motherboard is an ASRock X570 PRO4.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit pricey, but the Corsair iCue Commander PRO can handle up to six 3-pin or 4-pin fans. It is powered via SATA from your PSU. I do not recall if it plugs into the case fan header as well, but I do know that it comes with four temperature sensors that you can use for more accurate temperature control. It also supports two individual lighting channels, which can be split (using the Corsair node pro) to connect multiple RGB fans and LED strips. Most of the fan controllers that have the functionality you are looking for will come with lighting/RGB management and cost about the same price; unfortunately most companies do not offer a cheaper alternative without the lighting control.

https://www.corsair.com/us/en/Categories/Products/Accessories-%7C-Parts/iCUE-CONTROLLERS/iCUE-Commander-PRO-Smart-RGB-Lighting-and-Fan-Speed-Controller/p/CL-9011110-WW

https://www.bestbuy.com/site/corsair-commander-pro-hardware-controller/6229603.p?skuId=6229603